# R- Left Join Insert to mariadb/mySQL using DBI dbExecute or other package

Tags: r, rmysql, r-dbi

Is it possible to use the DBI::dbExecute (or some other package) statement to perform a  Left Join while uploading data to an sql database from R?

I think it might be possible with dbExecute, but I don't know what the statement would look like to include the entire dataframe.

I have an existing table, and I need to join chunks of data as well as add rows that don't exist and fill the missing value with 0. But I'm not finding a way that lets me send an entire dataframe to be joined.

**Database Table**

```
Path1   Path2   File_Name   ID   Value1
root    home    Sample1     1    1
root    home    Sample1     2    0
root    home    Sample1     5    1
root    home    Sample1     7    1
root    home    Sample2     1    0
root    home    Sample2     2    1
root    home    Sample2     3    1
root    home    Sample2     4    1
root    home    Sample3     1    0
root    home    Sample3     3    1
root    home    Sample3     6    1
```

**DataFrame containing data that needs to be joined (on Path1, Path2, File_Name, and ID, placing 0 values in Value 1 where it adds new rows) to the database**

```
Path1   Path2   File_Name  ID  Value2
root    home    Sample1    1   5000
root    home    Sample1    2   9000
root    home    Sample1    5   400
root    home    Sample1    6   3500
root    home    Sample1    7   8500
root    home    Sample1    8   2200
```

**What the database would look like after it was updated**

```
Path1   Path2   File_Name   ID   Value1   Value2
root    home    Sample1     1    1        5000
root    home    Sample1     2    0        9000
root    home    Sample1     5    1        400
root    home    Sample1     6    1        3500
root    home    Sample1     7    0        8500
root    home    Sample1     8    0        2200
root    home    Sample2     1    0        
root    home    Sample2     2    1        
root    home    Sample2     3    1        
root    home    Sample2     4    1       
root    home    Sample3     1    0       
root    home    Sample3     3    1        
root    home    Sample3     6    1
```

And then I would keep doing this for the remaining chunks of data.

Comment: Take a look at `dbx::dbxUpsert()` .